# Problema al crear un pdf

Tags: fpdf

Tengo una aplicación hecha con PHP y MySQL. Para sacar reportes en PDF utilizo fpdf y la clase pdf_mc_table. Hasta aquí todo bien. El problema viene cuando el usuario, al hacer un presupuesto, en el campo descripción, pone un texto muy largo. Que hace esta librería? Cuenta la altura que tiene el campo descripción y si no cabe, pasa todo el registro a la siguiente página. Yo lo que quiero es que corte cuando llegue al final de la página y siga en la siguiente. A ver si me podéis ayudar. La librería pdf_mc_table, está disponible en GitHub por si no la conoceis. Gracias. Un saludo